# set env var in mac doesn't take an effect

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables

I have tried to set env var in Mac.

```
$ open ~/.bash_profile
```

shows:

```
export ADB_PATH=~/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools/adb
export PATH=$PATH:$ADB_PATH
```

I have restarted the machine but no effect:

```
$ adb
-bash: adb: command not found
```

what can be wrong?

**update**

have tried this too, with no help:

```
export ADB_PATH=~/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ADB_PATH/adb
```

or

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: Is the `adb` program installed in the directory `~/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools/adb/`?

Comment: there is an executable `adb` in `~/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools/`. Just checked now

Comment: You don't need to restart the machine, all you need to do is either open a new terminal session (window or tab), log out and log in again or `source ~/.bash_profile.` If you sure your ~/.bash_profile is correct, try looking at login files that are loaded after ~/.bash_profile and make sure they don't reset $PATH. ~/.bash_profile will not be used if you start a sub-shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entries in the PATH environment variable should be directories, not individual binaries. Change your PATH to:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: This is the way it works. Type `echo $PATH` to check that the `platform-tools` directory is there and that there are no typos.

Comment: `$ echo @PATH    returns:
@PATH`

Comment: Sure it does. How about what I wrote, what does it return?

Comment: I just wrote: it `returns: @PATH`

Comment: it prints @PATH as a literal, not as an alias

Comment: What if you type `echo $PATH` and not `echo @PATH`?

Comment: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35840/discussion-between-elad-benda-and-joni)

Comment: another small question. How can I create an alias to a scrip line?
like when I type on the terminal "clientdir" it will execute "cd ~/MyWorkingSpace/Client"

Comment: With an [alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html): `alias clientdir="cd ~/MyWorkingSpace/Client"`

Comment: many thanks. If I want an alias in the system scope( vs. terminal instance) - should I put it in some file?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or `.profile`. On some systems the shell init scripts also source `.bash_aliases` or `.aliases` so if one of those files exists on your system it may make sense to use them.

Comment: thanks. I have tried to find any of them using the `spotlight` and found none. Can you guide me where to find one of them?

Comment: the os x user interface hides files that have a name that begin with a `.` you have to use the terminal. further questions should be posted to http://apple.stackexchange.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/